# wxpython textctrl style dynamic text color

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I am trying to do a highlight editor with wxpython (textCtrl), the problem is that when I change the color of each word it is so slow and sometimes it does not take the color

```
import wx
from threading import Thread
import time


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(
            self, None, title='Variable TextCtrl style text color')
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.tc0 = wx.TextCtrl(
            self.panel, -1, pos=(10, 10), size=(350, 100), style=wx.TE_RICH | wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.tc0.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.ChangeText)
        self.tc0.SetFont(wx.Font(28, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False, u'Consolas'))
        self.SetDoubleBuffered(True)
        self.styleThread = StyleThread(self.tc0)

        self.Show()

    def ChangeText(self, event):
        self.styleThread.setApplyStyle(True)


class StyleThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, txtCtrl):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.applyStyle = False
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self.start()
        self.tc0 = txtCtrl
        self.lastStyled = 0

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.applyStyle:
                self.style()
            #Even if I change the time the program start to require more resources
            time.sleep(0.5)

    def style(self):
        try:
            endLine = self.tc0.GetInsertionPoint()

            startLine = 0 if endLine < self.lastStyled else self.lastStyled

            word = ""

            unitary = False

            while startLine < endLine:
                character = self.tc0.GetValue()[startLine]


                if not character.isdigit() and character != "." and not character in ["+", "-"]:
                    word += character

                if character in ["+", "-"]:
                    self.tc0.SetStyle(self.tc0.GetInsertionPoint(
                    )-1, self.tc0.GetInsertionPoint(), wx.TextAttr(wx.RED))
                    word = ""
                elif word.strip() in ["Derivar", "Integrar"] or word.strip() in ["Pi", "Grados"]:
                    self.tc0.SetStyle(self.tc0.GetInsertionPoint(
                    )-len(word), self.tc0.GetInsertionPoint(), wx.TextAttr(wx.GREEN))
                else:
                    self.tc0.SetStyle(self.tc0.GetInsertionPoint(
                    ), self.tc0.GetInsertionPoint()+1, wx.TextAttr(wx.BLACK))
                    unitary = True

                if unitary:
                    self.tc0.SetStyle(self.tc0.GetInsertionPoint(
                    )-len(word), self.tc0.GetInsertionPoint(), wx.TextAttr(wx.BLACK))
                    unitary = False

                self.tc0.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.BLACK))
                startLine += 1
            self.lastStyled = endLine
        except:
            print("ERROR")

    def setApplyStyle(self, applyStyle):
        self.applyStyle = applyStyle


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I have read so much, but I can't find a special event for that purpose, even though I have used StyledTextCtrl and I works so fine, unfortunally It is not fully accessible by screen readers, as it is the purpose of the application. I would like to know if is there any way to do it?. Thank you :D

Comment: Your thread is blowing out with `invalid range in wxTextCtrl::SetStyle` use `try..except` around your insertion point calculations. That should move you forward.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Thank you, I haven't seen that error, I will change it, but, It is so slow to use, don't you know a similar event to handle the style text?, because when I add 100 characters the component blinks so much, sometimes the Insert Point moves to another place and the style starts to move to other words. And this is the same code that I used in the StyledTextCtrl component and It works perfetlly

Comment: I just don't know, perhaps someone who has written their own editor may be able to help. `wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl` is a 1 to 1 mapping of the “raw” scintilla interface, I guess there's a reason for that, although it does make for a very complicated beast.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony okay, Thank you, I will see if I find out a better solution or maybe with less complexity